# Uploading a Jpeg image in Drupal 7?

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-7

I am uploading images using Media Gallery for Drupal 7. Using png image files is fine but when trying to upload jpg files I get the following error

```
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: 'public://bob-ross-landscape-painting-281-28.jpg' is not a valid JPEG file in image_gd_load() (line 237 of /web/stud/u0763092/Picture/modules/system/image.gd.inc).
```

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the error message, your .jpg file is not readable by PHP's [`imagecreatefromjpeg`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) function (par of the GD library). Are you sure your image is a valid JPG file ?